# AlertView with TextField in DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have a scenario like, In First installation of app, user should view an `UIAlertViewController` with `UITextField`, User should enter email id, if it is valid dismiss the `UIAlertViewController`, else without dismissing that `UIAlertViewController` need to prompt other `UIAlertViewController` Saying "Enter Valid Email ID", how to Achieve this?

Comment: but why you want in DidFinishLaunching

Comment: Because it should be like one time appear in first time installation @NarendraPandey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Some logic For Your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Here Scenario is that it will first prsent Alert saying Enter your email.
When you enter Email and click OK it check whether Email is valid or not.
if it is not Valid present another Alert showing your email is not valid.
meanwhile your first Alert will be dismissed at that time. when you again Press OK of AlertError. Again it will show AlertController of your textField Email.

```
-(void)Alert{
   
    UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Your Email" message: @"Enter Your Email"preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"E-mail";
        textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    }];
    
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSArray * textfields = alertController.textFields;
        UITextField * Email = textfields[0];
        
        if ([self validateEmailWithString:Email.text]) {
        }else{
            UIAlertController *alertError = [UIAlertController  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error"  message:nil  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            
            [alertError addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                    
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

            }]];
            
            [self presentViewController:alertError animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }]];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    
}
- (BOOL)validateEmailWithString:(NSString*)checkString
{
    BOOL stricterFilter = NO;
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```

This will work Perfect for You.

[image]

[image]

Now if there is error again present email alert.

Answer (score 1):

Please write this in  AppDelegate.m.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.



    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                    message:@"Message"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.tag = 1000;
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];

    return YES;
}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (alertView.tag == 1000) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text);
        NSString *str = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        if ([str isEqualToString:@"your string"]) {

            //do what ever you want.
        }else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrong Email"
                                                            message:@"Please try again"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            alert.tag = 1001;
            [alert show];

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sure i will try and let you know @Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Add the delegate for UIActionSheet and TextField in the `AppDelegate.h` as

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

Add the delegate for UIActionSheet and TextField in the AppDelegate as 
First check idk the user is opening the app for the time. For doing this you can you can use this code in the `AppDelegate's` 
`applicationDidFinishLaunching` method:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
 //Now set up an alertView with textField:
UIAlertView *alertView1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ALERT!!!" message:@“Enter Email ID” delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            alertView1.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
            self.passwordField = [alertView1 textFieldAtIndex:0];
            [alertView1 setTag:10003];
            self.passwordField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
            [alertView1 show];
}
}
```

Now set up the delegate method for alertView as:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(alertView.tag == 10003) {

        if (buttonIndex==1) {
            [self.passwordField resignFirstResponder];
            NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
      NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:email])
     {
     //Do nothing

     } 
            else {
                //Show alert View for failed case
                UIAlertView *al = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please Enter Valid Email" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [al show];
                al.tag = 10004;
            }
        }
```